How to disable (parts of) company
How can one disable all abc … (text) suggestions in company-mode writing LaTeX? I’d just like to keep the snippet suggestions. – Thanks.

https://company-mode.github.io/manual/Backends.html

Thank you. This seems to do the job. I am on doom and could not figure out where/ how to set the variable permanently. Any ideas?

I'm not using doom, but seems config.el

Where to place it - as in comment - in config.el. And how to do it: You can read this in file your doomemacs dir/modules/completion/company/README.org:
To unset the backends for a particular mode, pass ~nil~ to it:
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(after! sh-script
  (set-company-backend! 'sh-mode nil))
#+end_src

Similar for enabling company backend in certain modes.
